# which one among the meta tag, php header and htaccess is a better cache system?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

The html meta tag for cache control, mod rewrite and php header tag

```
<filesMatch ".(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|flv|pdf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400"
</filesMatch>

<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public">

header('Expires: Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT');
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

Which cache system is better and why ?? php, htaccess or meta tags?

Answer (score 3):

Neither of them.

Only your first option will actually tell browser to cache images (though it has nothing to do with mod_rewrite).

However, I wouldn't bother with max-age anyway. Browsers are good enough with caching images, there is no need to force it manually

Comment: Practically caching images and other static resources should be the focal point, as the dynamic content should be...dynamic (and the static resources should be the vast bulk of shared data, and be served directly by the Web server).  Using a combination of a far future expiration and versioning the URL can allow for great control over requests.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that your examples are setting different headers and values in each case, the result in the browser will be the same whichever method you use. The main difference is in the kinds of files each can apply to:

- a `<meta>` tag can only appear inside an HTML document; consequently, you cannot use it to control cache validity on non-HTML files (such as images), and it's possible that something would download the file without processing the HTML and spotting the tag.
- the PHP `header()` function can affect any file that you are serving dynamically with PHP. This could include, for instance, plain text or XML files, but might not include an HTML file you'd uploaded fully formed to your server. You could pass static files, including images, through PHP, but this would be an inefficient way of serving them.
- the Apache `Header` directive (not part of `mod_rewrite`) can be applied to **any** file that Apache is serving, whether it is dynamically generated or not. This can include images, static HTML, CSS, and JS, plus whatever content you generate with PHP.

The only disadvantage of the Apache directive is that depending on your setup and how experienced you are with Apache's configuration rules, it may be fiddlier to maintain more complex rules for different bits of data. So for data already being processed with PHP, you may want to build something with the `header()` function if you want more fine-grained control.